# How to disable other drop down when selecting one from all drop down

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable other drop down when selecting one from all drop down.
can someone help me to answer my question?
help me please find the correct code for this?

```
  <script>
     function disableDrop(elem) {
            if(elem.value == '2'){
                document.getElementById('row2').disabled = true;
        } else {
             document.getElementById('row2').disabled = false;        
          }
      }
       function disableDrop1(elem) {
             if(elem.value == '1'){
                 document.getElementById('row1').disabled = true;
            } else {
               document.getElementById('row1').disabled = false;        
         }
          }
     </script>

    <form ID = "frmMain">
          <select ID = "row1" onchange = "disableDrop(this);">
                <option value = "1" selected>1</option>
                    <option value = "2" selected>2</option>
             </select>

    <select ID = "row2" onchange = "disableDrop1(this);">
                <option value = "1" selected>1</option>
                <option value = "2" selected>2</option>
            </select>
       </form>
```

Comment: *"help me please find the correct code for this?"* - Find it? Don't you have it now? That sure looks like code to me.

Comment: You should make it clearer what you are trying to make happen.

Comment: How do I disable drop down box when you choose one ? For example I was five drop down box then if I should pick one disabled those others .

Comment: Why does this have a `php` tag? This doesn't require server-side or contain any `php`. You should also be more clear with your question because from reading your question it would appear you're missing the main drop down that identifies what tables should/shouldn't be disabled.

Comment: ah.. okay, i'm trying to ask in a way where i can ask what I want because i'm not good in speaking in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Updated:** One select to enable/disable others.

The `values` of the first select options **must** match the **`ID`** of the select you want to keep enabled. 
For Example:

```
<option value="row1">Drop List One</option>
```

Will Keep this this enabled

```
<select id="row1" class="Drops">
   <option value = "1" selected>Drop List 1</option>
   <option value = "2" >2</option>
</select>
```

---

**Full Source Code:**

```js
function DropEvents(){
 var Lists=document.getElementById('Category');
  Lists.addEventListener('change', DisableMenu ,false);
}
function DisableMenu(){
  var Lists=document.getElementsByClassName('Drops');
 for(var i=0; i<Lists.length; i++){
  if(Lists[i].id!==event.target.value){
   Lists[i].disabled=true;
  }else{
      Lists[i].disabled=false;
    }
 }
}
window.onload=DropEvents;
```

```html
  <select id="Category">
        <option value="row1">Drop List One</option>
        <option value="row2">Drop List Two</option>
        <option value="row3">Drop List Three</option>
        <option value="row4">Drop List Four</option>
        <option value="row5">Drop List Five</option>
  </select><hr/>
   <select id="row1" class="Drops">
           <option value = "1" >Drop List 1</option>
           <option value = "2" >2</option>
    </select>
 <select id="row2" class="Drops" disabled="disabled">
           <option value = "1" >Drop List 2</option>
           <option value = "2" >2</option>
   </select>
   <select id="row3" class="Drops" disabled="disabled">
           <option value = "1" >Drop List 3</option>
           <option value = "2" >2</option>
   </select>
   <select id="row4" class="Drops" disabled="disabled">
           <option value = "1" >Drop List 4</option>
           <option value = "2" >2</option>
   </select>
   <select id="row5" class="Drops" disabled="disabled">
           <option value = "1">Drop List 5</option>
           <option value = "2" >2</option>
   </select>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for this code... this is the code what I'm trying to say.. thanks a lot..

Comment: okay.. thanks.. can I ask another question? hehe

Comment: You can ask another question, providing it isn't going to expand your original question too much.

Comment: okay2x.. in that code, how can I enable when I choose Drop List1,Drop List2,Drop List3,Drop List4, or Drop List5?

Comment: how to mark this answer as Answered?

Comment: So you want one drop down list that will select which other drop down lists will be enabled/disabled?

Comment: yes... if i'm going to choose one of them the others will disables then if i'm going not to choose all will be enabled

Comment: I will change the answer and work this in for you.

Comment: okay2x.. thanks a lot.. :D this will help me a lot. thankyou very much

Comment: Answer updated, I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks..  this will help me a lot..

Comment: can i ask again another question? how can i add the total value of all drop down box?

Comment: This questions seems to be expanding more and more, you can ask but you might need to submit a new question *(depending)* on the question.

Comment: that is my last question.. hehe :) i've been trying to add the values of all drop box but it has no return value

Comment: To get the value, `document.getElementById("row1").value;`  will = to the value of `row1` select.

Comment: i don't get it.. tsk

Comment: This website might help you, I wish you all the best. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp

Comment: hehe.. okay2x thank again for helping me in my project :D